# Finding several words from text and what is found instert into a table

Tags: python, sql, text, datatable, insert

I have a table with a column named "Job Description" with a lot of text.
I want to find specific words and what is found to insert into a table with his ID.
For example, this is my main table:

| ID | Job Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Are you eager to roll up your sleeves and harness data to drive policy change? Do you enjoy sifting through complex datasets to illuminate trends and insights? Do you see yourself working for a values-driven organization with a vision to tackle the most pressing injustices of our day? We are looking to hire a bright, hard-working, and creative individual with strong data management skills and a demonstrated commitment to immigrant's rights.**Power BI** The Data Analyst will assist with analysis and reporting needs for Veras Center on Immigration and Justice (CIJ), working across its current projects and future Vera initiatives. Who we are: Founded in 1961, The Vera Institute is an independent,**Power BI** non-partisan, nonprofit organization that combines expertise in research, technical assistance, and demonstration projects to assist leaders in government and civil society examine justice policy and practice, and improve the systems people rely on for justice and safety. We study problems that impede human dignity and justice. We pilot solutions that are at once transformative and achievable.**Qlik Sense** We engage diverse communities in informed debate. And we harness the power of evidence to drive effective policy |
| 1 | Overview Provides analytical and technical support for the integration of multiple data sources used to prepare internal and external reporting for the Quality Management team and business stakeholders. Provides support and analytical insight for Quality Incentive measures, HEDIS measures, and Quality Improvement initiatives.**Data Studio** Monitors, analyzes, and communicates Quality performance related to benchmarks. Collaborates with clinical and operational teams within Quality Management, as well as with CHOICE Clinical Operations and Business Intelligence & Analytics (BIA). |

I want to search and find it is in the column "Job Description" there are words like "Power BI", "Qlik Sense", "Data Studio". if those words are in the text, insert it and his ID  to a table with the columns "ID" and "DataVisualization". which looks like:

| ID | DataVisualization |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Power BI |
| 0 | Qlik Sense |
| 1 | Data Studio |
| 1 | Power BI |

I don't know if it is possible to do it in a query or another way. Please advise me what to do!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
input_table = []
output_table = []
word_list = ["Power BI", "Qlik Sense", "Data Studio"]
id_list = [0, 1]  # Treating as a list to allow an id to be missing

input_table.append("Are you eager to roll...effective policy")
input_table.append("Overview Provides...& Analytics (BIA).")

for id in id_list:
    for word in word_list:
        if word in input_table[id]:
            output_table.append([id, word])
print(output_table)
```

The output is

```
[[0, 'Power BI'], [0, 'Qlik Sense'], [1, 'Data Studio']]
```